# No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'

Tags: angular, forms

In my angular app I have `registration.component.html` below:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="registrationProcess()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email"  
               #email="ngModel">
        <small [class.d.none]="email.invalid && email.touched"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Full Name :</label>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Enter full name"   
               formControlName="fullname">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Enter password"  
               formControlName="password1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Enter confirm password"  
               formControlName="password2">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    <button style="background-color: rgb(59, 17, 99); 
                   margin-left: 80px;" 
            class="btn btn-info" 
            (click)="goToLogin()">
        Login
    </button>
</form>
```

This is from my `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NavigationModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
],
```

but it gives me the error below:

> No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Where'd you get this syntax from? `#email="ngModel"`. -> `[(ngModel)]="someValue"`

Answer (score 0):

Use only #email instead of #email="ngModel"

Comment: Please include more details in your answer. Why is it wrong to use the OP's way, and how is your version different? Remember, this post may be read by someone less familiar with the framework, and we have to help them understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `RegistrationComponent` added to declarations in `app.module` file.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
   RegistrationComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
```